# VS Code terminal fails to use npm version from nvm

Tags: npm, terminal, visual-studio-code, nvm

I'm using nvm on my Terminal and successfully installed node 10.2.1, which also installed npm 6.1.0. However, when I go to my VS Code editor, it gives me warnings in the integrated terminal for:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.2.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4,6, 7, 8, 9.
```

Turns out, it is actually using npm 5.5.1 (`npm -v`).

I check to see what's up with that and tried to dig further and eventually used: `which npm` on both integrated terminal and Mac's CLI.

Mac's Terminal shows:
`/Users/Aiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.2.1/bin/npm`

VS Code's Terminal shows:
`/usr/local/bin/npm`. Which is interesting, because if you do `which node` in this terminal, it results in the appropriate `/Users/Aiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.2.1/bin/node`.

I'm not sure how to get my VS Code terminal to point to the appropriate npm install through nvm. Not sure if it helps, but I checked `npm get prefix` and `npm -g bin` to find `/Users/Aiz/.nvm/versions/node/v10.2.1`. The only difference I'm finding is where each terminal is using npm from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up looking through VS Code issues on GitHub and came across something relevant to NVM and node issues. It fixed my issue since the underlying cause was the same.

Essentially what happened is that I had a global install of node before that I removed prior to using NVM but hadn't removed my global install of npm. This was causing conflicts in VS Code's terminal (not Mac's terminal). In order to fix this, you essentially have to find the symlink for `which npm` and remove the node_modules and npm associated recursively.

Here's the link you'll need: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/integrated-terminal.md#why-is-nvm-complaining-about-a-prefix-option-when-the-integrated-terminal-is-launched.

Don't forget to restart your editor after.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to implement this.  https://medium.com/@kinduff/automatic-version-switch-for-nvm-ff9e00ae67f3

Basically, nvm will check for a .nvmrc and switch or default each time you go to a new directory in shell.

It does have a dependency on zsh.

Comment: This also fixes vscode version control when trying to execute node based commit hooks! 

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me on Ubuntu:

A.) sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm

B.) Removed lines in my .bashrc that added the npm package directory to the path.

C.) Restart VS Code.

I doubt step A is necessary. But B and C certainly are.